# jQuery grid for mvc3 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, slickgrid, flexigrid, jquery-ingrid

What are the most recommended free jQuery grid for mvc3 razor? 
has good documents and samples

which one is for mvc3?

- Flexigrid: http://flexigrid.info/
- jQuery Grid: http://www.trirand.com/blog/
- jqGridView: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGridView
- Ingrid: http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/
- SlickGrid http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None is for MVC 3 or what version you want.

**They all target HTML and Javascript using the jQuery Framework.**

If you want to use any of those in your list, **you are able to do so**, just see what is the markup they want and create your grid that way.

---

as an example:

[jQuery TableSorter 2.0](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

it askes for a grid with this markup

```html
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

so, all you need to do **is making that markup in your View**

as a simple example:

```csh
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody>     

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<tr> 
    <td>@item.lastname</td> 
    <td>@item.firstname</td> 
    <td>@item.email</td> 
    <td>@item.due.ToString("c")</td> 
    <td>@item.url</td> 
</tr> 
}

</table>
```

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid 

VS 

http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx

which one is better?

Comment: both are paid components, why choose a paid one? Keep it simple! You will enjoy jQuery TableSorter. And no one here will tell you what is best, it's all up to you, see the details, check their support, see own often they reply back, ask some question on your upcoming project and choose for your self.